# Why do we use "on" for planetary bodies, rather than "in" like for locations on earth?

Tags: single-word-requests, reason-why

I'm new on this community, apologies if the question is not pertinent here.

I'm curious about whether there is a logic behind this, why, and when did it start. You never hear "in the moon", it's always "on the moon", why?. Thank you.

Comment: _on the moon_ means _on the surface of the moon._ _in the moon_ isn't perhaps of much interest to astronomers. [Just like we don't hear _in the earth_ as much as _on the earth._]

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+earth%2Cin+earth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20earth%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20earth%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's "The Man in the Moon" because the image of a man's face is perceived as being embedded in the moon's textures.